# Normalize JavaScript Object onto nested object from flat object when using Angular FormControlls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

the issue stems from using angular form controls refactored from ngModel

```
this.form.addControl('Contact.Attributes.firstname', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
```

NgModel refactored

```
[(ngModel)]="object.Contact.Attributes.firstname">
```

So i have a "flat" object that i need to turn into a normalized object of nested values.. is there a clever way to do this without writing my own parser?

turn this into (this.form.value)

```
{
 Contact.Attributes.firstname: "", 
 Contact.Attributes.middlename: "", 
 Contact.Attributes.lastname: ""
}
```

Into this

```
Contact: {
  Attributes: {
    firstname: "",
    middlename: "",
    lastname: "",
}
```

Comment: Why you are using addControl, is it some  kind of dynamic form? Normally you would construct your form in ngOnInit method like [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try,

```
const unflatten = require('flat').unflatten;

unflatten({
    'three.levels.deep': 42,
    'three.levels': {
        nested: true
    }
})
```

Result:

```
// {
//     three: {
//         levels: {
//             deep: 42,
//             nested: true
//         }
//     }
// }
```

https://github.com/hughsk/flat

Comment: this is what i was looking for ill give it a shot soon

Comment: While this answers the question perfectly i ended up going with Arek Kostrzeba solution, this will remain the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

### For Reactive Forms

```
/**
 * Add a control to this group.
 *
 * This method also updates the value and validity of the control.
 *
 * @param name The control name to add to the collection
 * @param control Provides the control for the given name
 */
addControl(name: string, control: AbstractControl): void;
```

It means that you can pass FormControl or FormGroup object to addControl method cause both these objects are instance of AbstractControl. Moreover even your this.form is instance of FormGroup

```
/** Component */
this.form.addControl('Contact', new FormGroup({
    Attributes: new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      lastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    })
}));

/** Template bindings */
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <div [formGroup]="form.controls.Contact.controls.Attributes">
    <input formControlName="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <input formControlName="lastName" id="lastName" type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</form>
```

---

### For Template Based Forms

wrap your input with [ngModelGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModelGroup#description) directive

```
<div ngModelGroup="Contact" >
  <div ngModelGroup="Attributes" >
    <input [(ngModel)]="object.firstname" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

then your data will arrive to your component in the form you want.

[Here](http://embed.plnkr.co/PxkLiZTDRlB5o0VVo9pp/) you can play with live example. create-event.component has ngModelGroup location.

Comment: that is a ton more markup that i would like to do, there could be a lot of groups on any given page unfortunately .. (the api im using is poorly designed )

Comment: This is how they disign it. Solution with unflatten looks a bit hacky in Angular context, but is good enougth for simple forms. For complex forms or dynamic forms it is better to follow Angular rules in my opinion.

Comment: you know you are probably right, im actually trying this way right for comparison. A gotcha i found is that form.get('name.with.dots'), is returning null

Comment: To access childs use controls property `form.controls.Contact.controls.Attributes`. Ofcorse you have to build your form Angular way to do that

Comment: hmm this works as expected `[formControl]="form.controls.Contact.controls.Attributes.get('firstname')`, seems awfully verbose. but i can at least validate the entire form and add and remove rules as needed

Comment: might have to go this route in order to get the benefits of adding removing form fields dynamically  `*ngIf="form.controls.Contact.controls.Attributes.get('firstname')"`

Comment: so i changed it up to `[formControl]="form.get('Contact').get('Attributes').get('firstname')"` keeps the IDE happy and is a few characters less

Comment: You can declare your controls as public proprties on your component, then you can use this properties directly in the template. It's some kind of shorthand. I will edit my answer later.

Comment: seems like a trade off, i will have a bunch of children so the amount of properties vs convince is a trade off. honestly this works perfect